# How to use @State and @Environment properties in a struct that can produce a view but isn't a view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I’m trying to create a view style for customizing a custom SwiftUI view that I’m developing. I declared a protocol with a `makeBody` function, I’m storing the style as a `@State` property so it can be updated, and I’m calling `makeBody` from inside a view. This technique closely follows [what SwiftUI already does](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view-styles) but there’s one thing that I can’t figure out.

##### Problem

There’s one important behavior that the first-party view styles have that I can’t replicate — that’s using `@State`, `@Environment`, or any other SwiftUI property wrapper inside the custom view style.

For example, I can implement the following custom `ButtonStyle` that just displays the value of the current color scheme as the button’s content.

```swift
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Text(String(describing: colorScheme))
    }

}

struct MyView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Button("foo", action: {}).buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle())
    }

}
```

When I preview `MyView` with a `.dark` preferred color scheme, the `colorScheme` property of `MyButtonStyle` is updated, the `makeBody`  function is called again, and the text reads “dark”. This is all expected.

[image]

Now, let’s take a look at the custom view style that I created.

```swift
struct MyCustomStyle /* : CustomStyle */ {

    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    @ViewBuilder func makeBody(configuration: CustomStyleConfiguration) -> some View {
        Text(String(describing: colorScheme))
    }

}

struct MyView: View {

    @State var style = MyCustomStyle()

    var body: some View {
        style.makeBody(configuration: .init())
    }

}
```

In the above scenario, when I preview `MyView` with a `.dark` preferred color scheme, the `colorScheme` property is not updated, and the text reads “light” even though the label's foreground color has correctly picked up the change.

[image]

##### Question

How to make `@State` and `@Environment` properties work in the custom view style, just as they work in `ButtonStyle` and in views, without introducing any boilerplate to the implementation of `makeBody` function?

I'm certain that it's possible because all the first-party view styles already support this, without styles conforming to `View`, and without them implementing the private `_makeView` API that manually adds dependencies to SwiftUI's graph (at least according to the module interface of `SwiftUI`).

##### What I Tried That Didn't Work

I tried initializing the view style inside a computable `body` of a view that wraps `MyView`. That doesn't work either.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        MyView(style: MyCustomStyle())
    }

}
```

##### Unacceptable Answers

Wrapping the return value of the custom `makeBody` function in a separate view, with `colorScheme` property being part of that view, is a known workaround that results in correct behavior. Answers suggesting this as a workaround will not be accepted because this question is all about *avoiding that*.

Answers saying that it is impossible to use `@Environment` or `@State` outside of a type conforming to `View` will not be accepted (because it is possible, see `ButtonStyle`), unless they can *prove* that private API is what drives this.

Comment: All env variables work *inside* a calculable `body`, but your custom style is created *outside* body, so there is no mechanism to update it and it does not work.

Comment: @Asperi Can you elaborate? The view that uses custom style is initialized inside a calculatable body of another view, so the style property's initial value is created then. I tried doing that explicitly (see "What I Tried That Didn't Work" section) and it still doesn't work. Unless I misunderstood what you're saying?

Comment: As @Asperi alluded, `@Environment`, `@State`, `@ObservedObject`, etc., property wrappers only  update in `View` conforming structs.

Comment: @flopshot Untrue, see my example with `MyButtonStyle` which does not conform to `View`. You can try it yourself in a playground.

Answer (score 3):

We don't have access to whatever the [`EnvironmentKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentkey) is that corresponds with `ColorScheme`, but its `defaultValue` must be `light`. That's why you can ever get a value at all, outside of a view.

Your type won't ever actually be supplied with [`EnvironmentValues`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues) unless it's a `View`, `ViewModifier`, `ButtonStyle`, …Apple doesn't actually offer an exhaustive list of protocols that are considered "part of the view hierarchy".

What you're trying to do, which is unfortunately currently impossible, is to implement your own `Style`. There is no protocol that all of the built-in `Style`s use, requiring an implementation of

```swift
makeBody(configuration: Configuration)
```

For example, the `ButtonStyle` documentation tells us,

> The system calls this method for each Button instance in a view
> hierarchy where this style is the current button style.

All of the following fit the same profile. You can implement one of these styles, but you can't make a type that conforms to some parent `Style` protocol.

- [ButtonStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/buttonstyle/makebody(configuration:))
- [ControlGroupStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/controlgroupstyle)
- [GaugeStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gaugestyle)
- [GroupBoxStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/groupboxstyle)
- [LabelStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/labelstyle)
- [MenuStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menustyle)
- [PrimitiveButtonStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/primitivebuttonstyle)
- [ProgressViewStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/progressviewstyle)
- [TableStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tablestyle)
- [ToggleStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/togglestyle)

If you don't conform to one of the "view hierarchy" protocols, then relying not on the environment, but rather, dependency injection, is necessary. E.g.

```swift
struct MyCustomStyle {
  init(environment: EnvironmentValues) {
    colorScheme = environment.colorScheme
  }

  private let colorScheme: ColorScheme

  @ViewBuilder func makeBody() -> some View {
    Text(String(describing: colorScheme))
  }
}
```

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @Environment(\.self) private var environment

  var style: MyCustomStyle { .init(environment: environment) }

  var body: some View {
    style.makeBody()
  }
}
```

---

You have to give up on what you actually want to do unless you go work on SwiftUI at Apple. However, you should evaluate if you can get away with a targeted functionality subset. E.g.

```swift
struct MyCustomStyle: ViewModifier {
  struct CustomStyleConfiguration { }

  @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

  init(configuration: CustomStyleConfiguration = .init()) {
    self.configuration = configuration
  }

  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    Text(String(describing: colorScheme))
  }

  private let configuration: CustomStyleConfiguration
}
```

```swift
struct MyView: View {
  var body: some View {
    EmptyView()
  }
}

extension MyView {
  func style(_ style: MyCustomStyle = .init()) -> some View {
    modifier(style)
  }
}
```

```swift
MyView().style()
```

---

Your question also mentions `State`, but you didn't supply an example for it. You probably just need to conform to [`DynamicProperty`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicproperty) for whatever you're doing with `State`.

Comment: You said that "your type won't ever actually be supplied with EnvironmentValues unless it's a View, ViewModifier, ButtonStyle". But I inspected SwiftUI's module interface file and while `View`-conforming types do implement SwiftUI's hidden `_makeView` functions that allow them to "register dependencies", `ButtonStyle`-conforming types are free of them.

Comment: This suggests that the magic happens elsewhere, somewhere in `Button` or perhaps in `buttonStyle`'s view modifier type. I am (perhaps naively) hopeful that this is possible, albeit convoluted, to achieve in third-party code, I just can't figure our where exactly.

Comment: The dependency injection solution is not satisfactory to me, because it introduces more boilerplate than just wrapping the result of `makeBody` in a separate `View` and using `@Environment` there. This question is about replicating `ButtonStyle`'s behavior.

Comment: It's not satisfactory to me either! But it's documentation of what you're asking for  with `@Environment` being impossible. It's not obvious from your question why you're not okay with making your own `Style`s `View`s. Apple's are not, but they might as well be. Did you actually have a question about `@State`, or should you edit the question to get rid of that part?

Comment: I focused on `@Environment` more than on `@State` in the question but both are equally important for me. I did not edit the question beyond minor things. What I want to do is to vend a view in a third-party library that offers `ButtonStyle`-like customizations to modify a part of its internal hierarchy (much like `ButtonStyle` for `Button`).

Comment: For this, the view needs to pass a configuration that the style implementation could use to produce a proper customization, so it needs to be a function from configuration to view. I omitted it for simplicity but I can see now that it's an important detail. I edited my question to include this.